# vim:filetype plugin conflict

Tags: vim, plugins

I need to do python and js program at the same time.

And also, I have some language specific seetings located at the ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ directory

Here I'll show you the content of these files:

In python.vim

```
    set tabstop=4
    set shiftwidth=4
    set expandtab
    set softtabstop=4
    nnoremap Y :Autoformat<CR>
```

In my javascript.vim

```
    nnoremap Y :call JsBeautify()<CR>
```

Imagine this scenery:

- Open a python file using vim
- Then open a js file in a new windown using `:split`
- Now whenever I press **Y**
- Vim will call `JsBeautify` even if I'm editing the python file

That's not what I want

Now I'm wondering if there is a way to make vim work like this:

- Judge the filetype of the current window
- And source the specific *.vim file in accordance with the filetype from the  ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ directory
- Then in the above-mentioned scenery
- It will call `Autoformat` when I am editing the python file and `JsBeautify()` when I am editing the js file
  ~

Comment: `:h setlocal` and `:h :map-local`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must make your options and mappings as *local* as possible.

In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal expandtab
setlocal softtabstop=4
nnoremap <buffer> Y :Autoformat<CR>
```

In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> Y :call JsBeautify()<CR>
```

As FDinoff wrote in his comment:

```
:help :setlocal
:help :map-local
```