# Vim mixes up indent style when editing different files

Tags: vim, indentation, nerdtree

I am using the [nerdtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) with some [other plugins](https://github.com/bodokaiser/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc#L9-L38).

When I edit files with different indent settings (e.g. `Makefile` which requires tabs and `*.js` which should have spaces) then vim mixes up both and applies tabs to `*.js`.

The file type stuff is defined in [these lines](https://github.com/bodokaiser/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc#L102-L114):

```
" use real tabs for these languages
autocmd FileType go,make
            \ set noexpandtab

" use two spaces for these languages
autocmd FileType ruby,html,json,jade,javascript
            \ set tabstop=2 |
            \ set shiftwidth=2

" use four spaces for these languages
autocmd FileType css
            \ set tabstop=4 |
            \ set shiftwidth=4
```

Any idea how to make vim to reapply `autocmd Filetype` when opening another tab in nerdtree?

Bodo

Comment: Use `setlocal` instead of `set`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518262/vimfiletype-plugin-conflict

Comment: You shouldn't need to `set noexpandtab` for make files as vim already sets this for make files. See `:view $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/make.vim`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `setlocal` instead of `set` to prevent your settings from leaking to other buffers.